# Why GetFiles from a remote folder using Linq is hanging

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to fetch the files inside a folder ordered by LastWriteTime.

The code is running very fast when accessing to a local path (C:\MyFolder), but is hanging when accessing to a remote path (\\MyServer\MyFolder)

```
Dim myOrderedList As List(Of String) = (From item In IO.Directory.GetFiles(strFolderSource) _
        Let file = New IO.FileInfo(item) _
        Order By file.LastWriteTime _
        Select item).ToList()
```

Should this code work? Is not allowed this method to get files from a remote folder?
Which alternative code could I use to get the same result without hanging?

EDITED (2019-01-18 16:32):

Sorry guys, I've tried the proposed solution from Rango, and still the same hang. Finally I created a small logging system to catch the step that caused the problem, and realized that all is a credential problem.

Just before the code I posted I do a NET USE to grant access to the remote computer, and the net use is executed, but for any reason, the GetFiles() fails because of Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
So, Could I ensure the credentials with the net use before call the GetFiles()?

Maybe using a pause or something like this?

FULL CODE:

```
Dim processInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
processInfo.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\net"
processInfo.Arguments = "net use \\MyServer\IPC$ ""password"" /USER:Username"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo)

Dim myOrderedList As List(Of String) = (From item In IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\MyServer\g$\MyFolder") _
        Let file = New IO.FileInfo(item) _
        Order By file.LastWriteTime _
        Select item).ToList()
```

Comment: You can improve it a little bit by using `EnumerateFiles`

Comment: @Rango Would that be an improvement when the entire list is needed to do the ordering?

Comment: @Jortx How quickly does Windows Explorer show the contents of the remote directory?

Comment: @Jortx remote access is *remote* and depends on the remote machine's performance, CPU and network load. Your local drive works at 500MB/sec. A 1 Gbps network connection to a remote machine that goes through 1Gbps switches probably works at 50MB/sec or less.

Comment: @Andrew Morton & Panagiotis Kanavos - Indeed not quick as the local access, but I can access waiting 1 second, maybe 2 seconds sometimes, from Windows Explorer... My problem is not a speed problem, I could wait... My problem is a hanging problem, and a never ending process. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Jortx If you temporarily take out the code to do with the ordering, does it still hang?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead wich has two advantages:

1. No consecutive security handshakes from the remote server necessary
2. Streaming the files instead of loading all into memory before you start ordering them

---

```
Dim di = new DirectoryInfo(strFolderSource)
Dim files = From fi In di.EnumerateFiles() Order By fi.LastWriteTime Select fi.FullName
Dim myOrderedList As List(Of String) = files.ToList()
```

Comment: I compared using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles against Directory.GetFiles on a NAS directory (>7,000 files) and found the former to be noticeably faster, taking maybe half the time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved including a sleep of 5 seconds after the **net use** and before the **GetFiles()**:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Thanks for your time, and hope this helps anybody with a similar problem.

Comment: The code in [Rango's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253218/1115360) may give you a small but useful increase in speed, seeing as you're having to wait an extra 5 seconds.